# htaccess complex redirect advice

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that redirects from blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog

Its a WP site that also has a permalink redirect to change the url from date name to post.

The htaccess works perfectly on the blog.domain.com and it also works perfectly on the domain.com/blog.

The only issue is that coming from blog.domain.com/* ends with a double 301.

I have included both htaccess so you can see.

What I am looking to do is to get the blog.domain.com/ to pre apply the redirect match before redirecting to the domain.com/blog site.

Thanks

BLOG.DOMAIN.COM

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.EXAMPLE\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.EXAMPLE\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/EXAMPLE\.com\/blog\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

DOMAIN.COM/BLOG

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://EXAMPLE.com/blog/$4

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is an example URL that gets redirected twice and what is final URL you see in browser?

Comment: blog.domain.com/2014/07/page -> 301 to domain.com/blog/2014/07/page -> 301 to domain.com/blog/page

domain.com/blog/2014/07/page -> 301 to domain.com/page

Comment: `/page domain.com` is strange. Comment out `RedirectMatch` line and then test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.